# Why do variables of inner functions not leak to the outer scope?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet of JavaScript:

```
function outer() {
    var x = 10;
    function inner() {
        var y = 20;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the variable `y` is not available in the context of `outer`. Following through the process in the ES5 spec tells us that this is what happens when we enter the `outer` execution context:

- We enter a new execution context ([10.4](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4))
- Since it's a function, we follow the steps outlined in [Entering Function Code (10.4.3)](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4)

  - Let *code* be the value of *F*’s [[Code]] internal property.

The [[Code]] internal property of a function is described in [Creating Function Objects (13.2)](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2). It refers to the *FunctionBody* as specified by the grammar (the entire contents of the function):

> `function` *Identifier* `(` *FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub>* `) {` *FunctionBody* `}`

At this point we enter the [Declaration Binding Instantiation (10.5)](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) section and do the following:

- Create bindings for any arguments in the formal parameter list of the function
- For each function declaration in *code*:

  - Create a binding in the current scope between function identifier and a `Function` object (created as specified in [Function Definition (13)](http://es5.github.com/#x13))
  - **There is nothing to say "remove the function we've just processed from *code*"**
- Create a binding for the `arguments` object
- For each variable declaration in *code*:

  - Create a binding in the current scope for the variable identifier

My question is why, at this point, are bindings not created for variable declarations from inner functions? It seems like *code* should still contain the entire source text of the outer function (which would include the source text of the inner function). I'm looking for something in the spec which explains the behaviour.

---

**Updated, to be a bit clearer**: I am asking about what happens when we enter the context of the `outer` function. The `inner` function is never called, and I don't care about what happens when we return from the `outer` function. I am purely interested in the process, as defined by the spec, of creating bindings for variable declarations when entering a new execution context.

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your thinking.

Javascript has function-scope. Thus you have a new execution context for each function, thats true. However, after you return from a function this function context expires. That is the reason why you can't access the variables from the inner function after it has returned. You still are in the execution-context of the outer-function but you can't access the execution-context of the inner function anymore.

Citing the [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4):

> Every return exits an execution context. A thrown exception may also exit one or more execution contexts.

EDIT: To clarify this further: The body of a function declaration is NOT being processed (see [10.5.5.d](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5)), only the function identifier and the arguments are passed to the variable environment.

Comment: I'm asking about the point at which you *enter* the outer function, not return from it. The spec says "Create a binding in the current scope for every variable declaration in the source text of the function". The function text includes any inner functions. It doesn't matter whether the inner function is called or not.

Comment: The moment you enter a function a new execution context is created. You are now in the context of inner, which has access to the outer context. You cannot be in the outer context and have access to the inner because either you are not still in or already have returned from inner. (Except you are calling `outer` from withing `inner`).

Comment: No. I am talking about entering `outer`, not `inner`. Follow through the steps in the question to see what I mean. Enter `outer`, "Declaration Binding Instantiation" occurs, why does that not create bindings for variable declarations appearing in inner functions?

Comment: because only the function-identifier is added to the variable environment. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, but *code* should contain the entire contents of `outer`. When you get to 10.5.8, variable declarations that appear in `inner` should still be in *code*. The question is, why are those variable declarations not part of *code*? Theres nothing in 10.5.5 that says "remove the source of the inner function from *code*".

Comment: There is no need to remove the functionbody of inner, because it is simply not evaluated/skipped because it's a functionbody of a function declaration.

Comment: Yes, and my question is where does the spec say that? In 10.5.8 the entire function body (which will include inner functions and their bodies) is parsed for variable declarations.

Comment: i already mentioned this in my answer. As a function declaration NEEDS to have a functionbody, when stating that the identifier is passed, then it is implicitely stated, that the body is of no further interest.

Comment: I see what you mean, but *code* is not changed, and 10.5.8 simply states that for every variable declaration in *code*, create a binding. *code* will still include variable declarations from inner functions. We know from experience that the inner function bodies are not of interest, but that behaviour doesn't seem to be apparent in the spec. It just says "find variable declarations in *code*, where *code* is the **entire contents** of the outer function".

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the [definition of the term *code* (§10.1)](http://es5.github.io/#function-code):

> *Function code* is source text that is parsed as part of a [*FunctionBody*](http://es5.github.io/#x13). The *function code* of a particular [*FunctionBody*](http://es5.github.io/#x13) does **not include** any source text that is parsed as part of a **nested** [*FunctionBody*](http://es5.github.io/#x13).